# Wordpress: Get post date on Category page

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

On Category page displaying post of particular category with title and post date. The issue is that it is getting the date for only the first list item while for the other list item it returns blank.

Here's my code:

```
 <div class="post-date">
  <?php the_date(); ?>  
 </div>
```

[image: not getting published date for other posts]

How can i display post published date with each post title?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this

```
<?php  the_time('F j, Y \a\t g:i a');  ?> or

<?php the_time(get_option('date_format')); ?>
```

When there are multiple posts on a page published under the SAME DAY, the_date() only displays the date for the first post (that is, the first instance of the_date()). To repeat the date for posts published under the same day, you should use the Template Tag the_time() with a date-specific format string.

Comment: As mentioned in [the Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_date) you can use `<?php the_time(get_option('date_format')); ?>` to automatically use the same date format as `the_date()`, which is the one configured in your WordPress settings. This helps to keep a consistent look across the site if the WordPress admin changes the date format.

Answer (score 1):

you may try the follow to get the post date

```
<?php the_time( get_option( 'date_format' ) ); ?>
```